# Perl array conversion from 2d to 1d

Tags: arrays, perl, data-conversion

Say I have 2-d array A like this,

```
my @A;

$A[0][0]="text1";
$A[0][1]="text2";
$A[0][2]="text3";
$A[1][0]="text4";
$A[1][1]="text5";
$A[1][2]="text6";
```

I want to convert it to another array B so that

`$B[0]` will contain `(["text1","text2","text3"])`

and

`$B[1]` will contain `(["text4","text5","text6"])`.

I have tried

```
my @B = $A[];
```

But it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you meant the square brackets in your question, because if you did, then the `@B` you want is actually the same as `@A`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, must be getting late.  I might to say somehow to set @B using @A so that @B = ["text1", "text2", "text3"] only.

Comment: You seem confused about what you want. What you describe to want in `@B` is not a one-dimensional array. What you want there is what you already have in `@A`. Perhaps you are not sure how arrays work in Perl?

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the new `@B` is what `@A` already contains. If you mean what I think you mean then you can do this with a simple `map`:

```
my @B = map @$_, @A;
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I also want: @C = ["text4", "text5", "text6"] only using @A?

Answer (score 0):

```
my @A;
$A[0][0]="text1";
$A[0][1]="text2";
$A[0][2]="text3";
$A[1][0]="text4";
$A[1][1]="text5";
$A[1][2]="text6";
```

Iterate the forloop and store the value into 2d array

```
for($i='0'; $i<=$#A; $i++)
{
    push(@{$B[$i]}, @{$A[$i]} );
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
print '$B[0][0]==>', $B[0][0], "\n";
print '$B[0][1]==>', $B[0][1], "\n";
print '$B[0][2]==>', $B[0][2], "\n";
print '$B[1][0]==>', $B[1][0], "\n";
print '$B[1][1]==>', $B[1][1], "\n";
print '$B[1][2]==>', $B[1][2], "\n";
```

May be this is helpful for your question.